# N-binacci numbers and ratios generated by them

Tags: real-analysis, fibonacci-numbers

I was bored at home today and playing with "n-bonacci" numbers, numbers generated by $$x_0=0,x_1=1,...,x_k=k; x_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_i$$
I made an assumption based upon the quadratic responsible for the golden ratio, that the ratio of sequential n-bonacci numbers could be found by solving the $n$-th degree polynomial
$$x^n-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^i=0$$
For example, if $n=2$, then we get as a real root $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, approximately $1.6180339...$.  If $n=3$, I let Maple generate the real root of $\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}+\frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}}+\frac{1}{3}$ approximately $1.83929...$
By using Maple, I started solving higher and higher degree polynomials and it seems that this ratio tends to 2 as $n$ gets large.  Should I use an induction proof?  Or is there a simpler way that I'm missing?

Comment: The $n$-deg polynomial you were playing with is a factor of $$x^n(2 - x) = 1$$ Thus (excluding the other factor $x-1$), as $n \to \infty$, then $x \to 2$. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limiting case is the following series: $x_i=0$ for $i\le 0$, $x_n=\sum_{i\le n} x_i$ for all $n> k$, with $x_1,\ldots, x_k$ arbitrary initial conditions.  This series has closed form $$x_{n}=2^{n-k-1}M  ~~(\text{for }n>k)$$ where $M=x_1+\cdots+x_k$.

This series is an upper bound for all of yours and has ratio $2$.  I provide this as evidence that 2 is the limit; a rigorous proof would require more care than I'm ready to spend at the moment.

Comment: what do you mean for $i\le{0}$?  Isn't $i$ an index?  I've never seen negative indices before (i don't think?)...

Comment: If you don't like negative indices, then make the sum $0\le i\le n$.

Comment: I thought that may have been where you were going, but I wasn't sure.  Thanks.  Any resources where I can find a proof?

Comment: Well, the first step is to prove that the largest polynomial root (in absolute value) equals $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n/x_{n-1}$.